# Javascript: Registering *every* DOM Element on creation/appending to DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, chromium-embedded, mutation-observers

In order to maintain a correct and highly responsive GUI overlay on a each website, I need to register and analyze every relevant DOM Element as soon as possible. Currently I am using a MutationObserver, which does this work for me and simplified, it looks like this:

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(
    function(mutations){
        mutations.forEach(
            function(mutation){
                if(mutation.type == 'childList')
                {
                    var nodes = mutation.addedNodes;
                    var n = nodes.length;

                    for(var i = 0; i < n; i++)
                    {
                        if(nodes[i].nodeType == 1) // ELEMENT_NODE
                        {
                            // Save it in specific Array or something like this
                            AnalyzeNode(nodes[i]);
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        );
    }
);

var config = {subtree: true, childList: true}; 

observer.observe(document, config);
```

But I've come to the realization, that the used MutationObserver isn't calling *AnalyzeNode* for **every** node contained in the DOM. When an already complete (sub)tree is created outside of the DOM (e.g. by executing an external JS script on page load) and you append its root to the DOM *mutation.addedNodes* will only contain the subtree's root and all of its children will go unnoticed (because no further mutations will take place there), being part of the DOM but not having been analyzed.

I had the idea of checking if the appended node may already have *childNodes* to identify it as root of an appended subtree, but unfortunately it seems like every *addedNode* may have children at the moment the MutationObserver's functions are called. So no distinction possible on this way.

I really don't want to double check every child node of an added node (the parent node) at the moment its parent node is processed by the MutationObserver. Most of the time, the child node will nevertheless be processed by the MutationObserver when itself will be part of *addedNodes* in an other occurring mutation and the overhead seems to get unnecessary high.

Furthermore, I thought about a Set of nodes, whose children have to be analyzed outside of a MutationObserver call. If an added node has children upon its appending to the DOM, the node is added to the Set. When another mutation takes place and one of its children is part of *addedNodes*, its child removes its parent from the Set by using *mutation.target* -- which is the parent node (*mutation.type* has to be *childList*). The problem with this approach is the timing when to check the children of the nodes in Set (and the fact, that I could query *document.getElementsByTagname* for every relevant Element type instead of maintaining a Set, but the timing problem is still there). Keep in mind that it should be as soon as possible to keep the overlay responsive and fitting to the website. A combination of *document*'s *onreadystatechange* and appending of new *script* nodes to the DOM (as indicator when external JS code is executed) might work even for websites, recreating parts of its content (I am looking at you duckduckgo search result page). But it seems like a workaround, which won't solve the problem in 100% of the cases.

So, is there another, more efficient way? Or does any of these approaches may be sufficient if slightly changed? Thanks a lot!

(Please try to avoid JQuery where possible as example code, thank you. And by the way, I am using CEF, so the best case would be a solution working with Webkit/Blink)

**EDIT1:** Website rendering is done internally by CEF and GUI rendering is done by C++/OpenGL with information obtained by the mentioned Javascript code.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://davidwalsh.name/detect-node-insertion - seems to do what you want to do, without node traversal

Comment: Maybe you can simply add a global CSS `@keyframes` rule that will draw the overlay on newly added element automatically, thus no MutationObserver at all?

Comment: @eithedog I'have seen this post before, but I think it would be necessary to add listeners to every node added, so again: a lot of additional (and also multiple) calls per node.

Comment: @wOxxOm website drawing is already done by CEF and GUI rendering takes place in C++/OpenGL, after sending website specific information via JS to C++ (I will add that to the original question)

Comment: @dm102 - no, author mentions only setting listeners on document (per different browsers) - you don't need to set listeners on nodes as events should propagate.

Comment: @eithedog Oh, I got it wrong, thx. At the moment, I am appending my own `<script>` element (containing the keyframe) to `document.head` and execute `document.documentElement.style.WebkitAnimation = "nodeInserted 3s 1";`. I started with a slow flickering, which the website completely executes, so animation is inherited by all nodes but `webkitAnimationStart` event seems to be fired only once. Child nodes don't seem to start their own animation.. Any ideas how they inherit animation but start it each independently?

Comment: @dm102 - children shouldn't inherit the animation; if you'd written `style.border = '1px solid #ff0000'` then given elements children wouldn't have been given a border, so unless I'm missing something about animations it should behave like any other style. If you define a listener on the document, the event that has been triggered by CSS defined animation should propagate from each of the nodes to the root - this way there's no need to define listeners on each of the nodes, but only on the root.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your actual goal is to layout detect changes in the rendered output, not (potentially invisible) DOM changes.

On gecko based browsers you could use `MozAfterPaint` to get notified of the bounding boxes of changed areas, which is fairly precise but has a few gaps, such as video playback (which changes displayed content but not the layout) or asynchronous scrolling.

Layout can also be changed via the CSSOM, e.g. by manipulating a `<style>.sheet.cssRules`. CSS animations, already mentioned in the comments, are another thing that can also affect layout without mutations. And possibly SMIL animations.

So using mutation observers alone may be insufficient anyway.

If your overlay has some exploitable geometric properties then another possibility might be sampling the parts of the viewport that are important to you via [document.elementFromPoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint) and calculating bounding boxes of the found elements and their children until you have whatever you need. Scheduling it via `requestAnimationFrame()` means you should be able to sample the state of the current layout on every frame unless it's changed by other rAF callbacks, running after yours.

In the end most available methods seem to have some gaps or need to be carefully tweaked to not hog too much CPU time.

> Or does any of these approaches may be sufficient if slightly changed?

Combining tree-walking of observed mutations and a `WeakSet` to not process already visited nodes may work with some more careful filtering.

- having already visited a node does not automatically mean you can skip its children
- but having visited a child without it being a mutation target itself should mean you can skip it
- removals events mean you must remove the entire subtree, node by node, from the set or just clear the set since they might be moved to another point in the tree

Answer (score 0):

MutationRecords seem to be [listed in the order in which the changes happened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35900620/what-is-the-order-of-mutationrecords-received-by-mutationobservers/45249725#45249725) (can be easily verified).

Before you run your `AnalyzeNode(nodes[i])` algorithm, you can run an `AnalyzeChanges(mutations)` step that can determine the over all change that happened.

For example, if you see `addedNodes` contains the same node 10 times, but you see the same node only 9 times in the `removedNodes` then you know that the net result is that the node was ultimately added to the DOM.

Of course it may be more complicated than that, you will have to detect added sub trees, and nodes that may have then been removed and added from those sub trees, etc.

Then finally, once you know what the net change was, you can run `AnalyzeNode(nodes[i])`.

I'm thinking about doing this to observe an entire `<svg>` tree and to render it (and re-render it when changes happen) in WebGL.

It may be tricky, because imagine the following happens synchronously by some user (you don't know what he/she will do) who is manipulating the DOM:

- a subtree is added (queues a record for the root node in addedNodes)
- a subtree of the subtree is removed (queues a record)
- then appended somewhere else outside of the first subtree (queues another record, oh boy.)
- an element is removed from the other subtree is removed (queues a record)
- and added back to the original subtree (queues a record)
- etc
- etc

Finally, you receive a list of MutationRecords that details all those steps.

We could loop through all the records and basically recreate a play-by-play of what happened, then we can figure out the final net changes that happened.

After we have those net changes, it'll be like having a list of records, but they will be simpler, (for example removing then adding a node simply cancels it out, so we don't really care if a node was removed then immediately added because the end result is basically nothing for that node).

People have tried to tackle the problem of detecting changes between trees.

Many of those solutions are associated with the terms "virtual dom" and "dom diffing" as far as web goes, which [yield](https://www.google.com/search?q=virtual%20dom&cad=h) [results](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&q=dom+diffing) on Google.

---

So, instead of doing all that mutation analysis (which sounds like a nightmare, though if you did it I would say please please *please* publish it as open source so people can benefit), we can possibly use a diffing tool to find the difference between the DOM before the mutation, and the DOM at at the time the MutationObserver callback is fired.

For example, virtual-dom has a way to [get a diff](https://github.com/Matt-Esch/virtual-dom#diff-computation). I haven't tried it yet. I'm also not sure how to create VTrees from DOM trees to pass them into the `diff()` function.

Aha! It may be easier to get a diff with [diffDOM](https://github.com/fiduswriter/diffDOM).

Getting a diff might present the simplest changeset needed to transition from one tree to another tree, which might be much easier than analyzing the a mutation record list. It's worth trying it out. I might post back what I find when I do it with the `<svg>`s...